# How to copy traffic from old server to new server?

Tags: log-files, migration

We are moving our server farm to AWS - and I want to fully test the new servers before sending them live traffic.

Question is:
How would I trap all incoming traffic and **copy** it to the new servers?

**For example**: I know the URLs are in the access logs. **How would I read the access logs in real time** (or similar) **and then send those URLs to the new server?**

Obvioulsy the response from the new server would go back to the old server and be ignored.

All the servers are running Ubuntu, if it makes a difference.

Comment: "Log replay" is the keywords you are looking for. There are many solutions that will take a existing access logs and replay the traffic while also taking the time-gab between requests into account. But generally we don't do product recommendations here.

Comment: @faker - Thanks for the correct keyword. I wasn't thinking in the direction of a product-recommendation, though that may save me the trouble of coding it myself.

Comment: OK, I've added it as an answer. For finding the right software you'll need to do some research. There are many out there, I don't think you'll need to write your own - most cover the usual configurations (Apache/Tomcat/Nginx/...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describing is usually referred to as "log replay".
Normally you feed an existing access log to the log replay program and it sends the requests again.
Some allow you to respect the time gab between the original requests, others also allow you to speed up the log replay.

Realtime replay could also be possible by configuring your webserver to (also) pipe access log to the program.
It will need to be able to support reading from there of course.